# How to pass v-for variable from view to component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a v-for shown in {{c.client_hashid}} and I want to pass this to component DeliverAdd. Here is my code so far.

```
<div class="client_card" v-for="c in all_clients" type="button"  data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#add_delievery_address"   > 
                  
    <div class="row">
        
    <div>
      <strong>{{ c.c_fullname }}</strong>
    </div>
                    
    <div>
      <strong>{{ c.c_address_1 }}</strong>
    </div>
                    
    <div>
      <strong>{{ c.c_address_2 }}</strong>
    </div>
        
    <div>
      <p>{{ c.c_city }}, {{ c.c_post_code }} </p>
    </div>
        
    <div> {{ c.client_hashid }} </div>
        
    </div>
    </div>
        
    <div class="modal fade" id="add_delievery_address" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="" aria-hidden="true">
                  
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
       <div class="modal-content text-black">
        
       <!--cannot pass information client_hashid to component DeliveryAdd-->                   
       <delivery-add :client_hashid="this.client.client_hashid"></delivery-add>
                          
        </div>
    </div>
        
    </div>
```

I want to pass client_hash_id to component `DlieveryAdd`, Here I've try

```
:client_hashid="{{client_hashid}}"
client_hashid="{{client_hashid}}"
:client_hashid="client.client_hashid"
:client_hashid="c.client_hashid"
```

but out of luck, I want when people click client_card, it will pass the `{{ c.client_hashid}}` and show the data hash id in `DlieveryAdd`, any help or suggestion would be appricate.

Comment: Isn't it just: `<delivery-add :client_hashid="c.client_hashid"></delivery-add>`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `this` in the Vue template

```
<delivery-add :client_hashid="client.client_hashid"></delivery-add>
```

Comment: One thing I concern is `c.client_hashid` is outside of for-loop, should I do `client.client_hashid` instead?

Comment: Yes, sure. But be sure you bind `client.client_hashid` with one `client_hashid`